# Question about reflection package

Tags: java, reflection

I read from sun website that for every reference jvm is creating one immutable class object 
  so that it can introspect the run time information of every class. And sun has mentioned to use .class syntax. I want to know the internal mechanism of this syntax and how it works.

Comment: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html explains the Class file format, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: you should probably start to accept some answers as correct. Go back to your questions and for each one, click the big tick of the answer you find most correct (if any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to start with [the reflection tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

The `.class` syntax is explained [on this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html) (no, it doesn't explain the inner workings)

Answer (score 1):

If compiled with `-target 1.4` or earlier, `Class.forName(String)` is called once and then `Class` reference stored in a synthetic static field in the calling class. For `-target 1.5` and later, a new version of the `ldc` ("load constant") bytecode operation references the class.

Use `javap -c` to see the bytecode that javac produces.

Comment: I have been coding in Java for more than tens years and I haven't a clue what you are trying to say here. ;)

Comment: @Peter: he's explaining what bytecode the `.class` syntax compiles to. It took me two passes to grok that as well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For each non-generic (or raw) **type** (Class, interface, array-type, primitive type) there is a Class object, created when this class is loaded. This object is not totally immutable, as it contains the static variables of the class, for example.

If you have an object, you can get the class object of its implementing class by calling `o.getClass()`. If you have some type, you can get its class object by `T.class` in Java.

From the class object you can inspect your class, to get constructors, methods, fields, superclass, implemented interfaces, and so on - this is called reflection.

(See the links in the other answers for more details.)

Comment: "as it creates the static variables of the class"? Could you provide some reference for that, I highly doubt that this is the case (or that it's specified that way).

Comment: @Joachim: (contains, not creates) It does not necessarily need to *contain* the static variables in the sense of being instance variables of the class object, but they are at least in some storage area referenced by the class object, and conceptually they **are part of the class object** (like the characters are part of the string or StringBuilder object, even if they are in a extra array).

Comment: ŭlo: see, this is where I disagree: I don't think the `Class` object **is** the class. It's a representation/handle of it, just as the `Method` object **represents** a method, but it **is** not the same as the method. The class and the methods *are not objects in Java*, if `Class` and `Method` were identical to the class and the method, then Java would be a quite different language.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer Mutable statics, as ever, make this really murky. To me, it makes sense to say that [lowercase-c] classes with mutable statics are mutable. [Uppercase-C] `Class`es are not keys but represent specific classes. So I don't think it unreasonable to say that `Class`es mutate (and that can be done through `get[Declared]Fields[s]`). Same as it reasonable to say that the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList` is mutable, even though only the array you supplied changes. OTOH, you could have an immutable list of mutable values.